# In C# using Entity Framework, get records which are 30 days due

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am new to C# world and Entity Framework.

I need to retrieve items from a table which are **over due in 30 days**. I am aware of the filtering I can do on the SQL side (with a stored procedure), but I am looking for a solution in Entity Framework.

This is my current code:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var deliverableItems = db.Deliverables
            .ToList() // fetch all records from Deliverable table.
            .Where(d => Is30DaysDue(d));

    foreach (var deliverable in deliverableItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(deliverable.DeliverableTitle);
        // perform action on due items....
    }
}

internal static bool Is30DaysDue(Deliverable deliverable)
{
    var deliverableDueDate = deliverable.DeliverableRevisedDueDate ?? deliverable.DeliverableDueDate.Date;
    var dateDiff = (deliverableDueDate.Date - DateTime.Now.Date).TotalDays;
    return dateDiff == 30;
}
```

As you can see in line 4, I am first retrieving all records from the `Deliverables` table and then doing the required filtering.

Is there any way to fetch 30 days due items using Entity Framework?

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention before, I have two dates `DeliverableRevisedDueDate` and `DeliverableDueDate`. If revised due date is null only then deliverable due date is considered.

Comment: So you want to retrieve data that are 30 days?

Comment: yes, wch are due in 30 days

Comment: I'm not sure if you know what Entity Framework is. It's basically a way to materialize the data in your database into C# objects. The current code is perfectly fine although you could put the `Where` before the `ToList` to do database-side filtering.

Comment: If I put ``where`` before ``ToList``, I get this exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method, and this method cannot be "

Comment: Because it can't translate your custom method to a built-in method in the database. Remove all the noise from the method and just use an inline lambda, it will understand that.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel forgot to mention before, I have two dates ``DeliverableRevisedDueDate`` and ``DeliverableDueDate``. if revised due date is null only then deliverable due date is considered, I'm not sure how to use both dates in inline lambda

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I've forgotten that some datetime functionalities does not support by linq to entity. so you have to use it like this

```
var newDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30);
 var deliverableItems = db.Deliverables
 .ToList() // fetch all records from Deliverable table.
.Where(d => d.DeliverableDueDate.Year == newDate.Year &&
d.DeliverableDueDate.Month == newDate.Month&&
d.DeliverableDueDate.Day == newDate.Day  );
```

Comment: when I try ``.Where(d => d.DeliverableDueDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30));`` . I get following exception An ``unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.``

Comment: @RG sorry, check this out